# Artifactory Pro - Legal way for testing Upgrade

Tags: artifactory

I want to upgrade my Artifactory Pro setup. I planned to clone the database, create a similar instance, and set up Artifactory Pro with the current production version, then upgrade the test instance to the latest version and make some tests(Upload artifacts, SAML, etc). If all tests will be Okay, upgrade the version of Artifactory Pro on the production instance.
How to be sure that I am making it legally? Do I need to request a Trial License? Or I can use my "production" key for a while?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reaching out to JFrog as having a license running on two Artifactory instances simultaneously is against the EULA (as it probably is to request a trial every time you need to do something not in prod). If it is production though you should consider having some sort of DR/test/dev/staging/qa setup, artifact availability is important